# Is there a way to distinguish between new's and new[]'s return value?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

Consider this code:

```
int *p = new int;
cout << sizeof(*p);
delete p;
```

As expected the result is 4. Now, consider this other code:

```
int *p = new int[10];
cout << sizeof(*p);
delete[] p;
```

I expected to get 40 (the size of the allocated array), however **the result is still 4**.

Now, suppose I have a function `int *foo()` that returns a pointer to a structure created with `new` or with `new[]` (but I don't know which one):

```
int *p = foo();
```

My question is, is there a way (or hack) to know if `p` points to a single integer or an array of integers?

*Please keep in mind that this is just a theoretical question. I won't be writing real code in this fashion.*

Comment: The more interesting question is, why we cannot read the size (item count) even though the runtime has to keep this information around.

Comment: You're right, now that I know it's not possible to obtain it directly it would be nice to know if there's some 'hack' to retrieve that value somehow.

Comment: You could if you did your own memory allocator, you could then have a function like get_allocated_size(*ptr) which would give you that information. Perhaps some OS have native calls that can give you that information but that's not part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way of doing that. But *you* know the difference, because the code you wrote called `new` or `new[]`.

The reason by the way that:

```
 cout << sizeof(*p);
```

gives you 4 in both cases is because p is a pointer to an int, the expression *p means the thing pointed to by such a pointer (i.e. an int) and the size of an int on your platform is 4. This is all evaluated at compile time, so even if `new[]` did return a special value, `sizeof` would not be able to use it.

Answer (score 3):

No, because your result is an address (that's why you get 4 for sizeof() in both cases). You created it, so you're expected to know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

In both examples the type of p is the same: int *.  sizeof operates on the type, not the data.  It's computed at compile time.

You have a couple of choices.  You can keep track of the array size yourself, or you can venture into using one of the containers in the standard library such as vector< int >.  These containers will track the size (e.g. vector< int >::size()) for you.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof(x) returns the amount of memory needed to contain x as declared.

There is no dynamic aspect to this at all.

sizeof (*foo) where foo is a `bar *` will always be the same as `sizeof(bar)`

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any way.

Obligatory question: Why do you need to know?

If it's "because I need to know whether to say `delete []` or `delete`", then just use arrays all the time, if for some obscure reason you can't figure out which one you used in your own code.

Comment: I was curious if there was a way to know if an array was created or not, because `delete[]` does know the size of the array to be deallocated when you call it. So the size of the array must be available (at least to `delete[]`). I wondered if this value could be retrieved somehow.

Comment: @Kanopus: The standard probably didn't allow for this for performance reasons.

Comment: @Kanopus - `delete[]` doesn't **always** have to know the size, but only if it has to call destructors for the objects. When it is an int array, it might be able to just release it to the OS without knowing the size. C++ also provides `std::vector` which keeps track of everything.

Comment: @Bo Persson: You're right. Perhaps the OS can take care of *some* array deallocations (without `delete[]` having to worry about the number of items). However, when working with objects we could assume that `delete[]` must know the number of objects in order to call their destructors. In the first scenario (if we knew the compiler implementation) we could retrieve the size of allocated memory from the OS. In the second case, and assuming we know the compiler implementation, can we retrieve the number of objects in the array?

Comment: @Kanopus - It might be possible, sometimes. For example, the MSVC compiler provides a function to ask for the size. The language doesn't require this to work everywhere though, and provides std::vector as a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Having a function that can return a pointer to a single item or an array is a bad design decision. You can always return a pointer to an array of size 1:

```
return new int[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `sizeof(*p)` returns always a value to the integer, so it's always returning **4**.

Now, how can you know whether `p` is pointing to `int` or `int[]` ?

There is **no standard way** of it. However, you can hack the platform and get it known. For example, if you try printing `p[-1], p[-2], ..., p[-4] etc.` for certain compilers (say linux in my case) then you will see a particular pattern in the value of this locations. However, this is just a hack and you cannot rely upon it always.